# Unable to add new rows to table in SQL server

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-insert

I've got a SQL Server 2016 table, with around 90,000 rows in it, a primary key, a few default values, nothing too fancy. I've also checked and the table has no triggers on it.

Until recently adding rows to it was no problem, but now when I try to add a new row it says its added it but when I check it hasn't. I've tried adding a row via a SQL statement (SSMS returns 1 row added) and via the GUI but still no new row, no warning or anything....

I've made a copy of the table and copied over its structure and data and that was fine and added my new data to it without any problem, then renamed it to take the place of the original table and poof! rows gone???

I've tried exporting all triggers from the database to see if there was another one linked to the table but found nothing there - so any suggestions where to look next is much appreciated!

Comment: Are you using implicit transactions or starting one and not committing? Maybe you have a synonym that's replacing the table being queried behind scenes?

Comment: Nope, not using a transaction in this instance. All other inserts work fine, just not on this table.

Comment: Any Triggers, perhaps? Without a replication, all we can do here is guess.

Comment: There are no triggers on the table and I even scripted all for the database out and none reference that table

Comment: Then i think the transactions are being Rolled back for some reason. Try tracing the `Rollback`

Comment: If the row isn't there, then either it was never inserted, or it was deleted afterwards. To check the first, verify that you're looking at the correct table by doing a `SELECT` in the same window where you do the `INSERT` -- do not use the GUI. If that shows the row isn't there, and you have verified there are no triggers, then the row was deleted by another process -- when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth.

Comment: It has to be a trigger but I can't for the life of me find it. I've added the row to a copy of the table, checked it exists and it did but when I swapped the tables over it deleted the row.

Comment: I found I could add rows to the middle of the table (Identity-insert) but not to the end (using the same SQL just with a different PK value), guess there must be a relationship somewhere that is restricting me to maximum value of 157480 (the column is an int)

Comment: Are you looking in the right spot for the new row? What does `DBCC CHECKIDENT('table')` tell you? Does the `COUNT(*)` change?

Comment: Checking identity information: current identity value '157523', current column value '157480', after trying to put a row in the identity value is increasing but the column value and row count doesn't change

Comment: If `select * from sys.triggers` doesn't show any triggers, then it's SQL profiler time to see if anything does something nasty with the rows as you add them.